# Android service that counts user taps on screen even when the application is closed

Tags: android, service, accessibility

there are some apps on play store like "tap counter" that can count number of touches on screen, including outside of app and even when the app is closed.
The only  way i can think of to do it is with accessibilty service  but those apps in play store dont seem to use accesibility . So you have an idea? Maybe code ex?

Comment: Name any app that has the capability that you describe.

Comment: Tap counter by wizardsapps

Comment: Thanks! I will test this app, to see if it works as advertised. If it does, I will work on getting the Android security flaw fixed. It should not be possible for an app to receive touch events without consuming those events. The only way for a "tap counter" to work over top of all other apps would require it to consume all the touch events, preventing the user from using those other apps. If they found a way around this, that has to be fixed, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Such applications requires the "Draw over other apps" (`android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`) permission.

> Allows an app to create windows using the type TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, shown on top of all other apps.

See for instance:
[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)